# Check for available records in datasets

Tags: sas

I have a HTML form with two details Name and category(it has three checkbox)

```
Name 

category : Easy   moderate high

submit button.
```

I have created dataset New that populate details of name and category whenever i click submit button.

For example if i give name as A and check easy option under category and click submit to create a dataset like below

```
Name   Category

  A     Easy
```

After this if i again give the same entry second time like name as A and check easy option under category and click submit to create  records in the dataset. It needs to verify the dataset New to check whether the entry is already available.

I need help such that it should not create the second records and should show message like it already available in ODS HTML output

It need to display the message like "new record created" if it is creating a new record.

Comment: What are you using to create this functionality? SAS/AF?

Comment: Sounds like web stores process environment ?   Are you asking how to check if the record already exists or how to display a message?

Comment: The webpage is developed in javascript. The above two variables name and category are created as macro variable, so that it can be called while writing the sas code.

Comment: I wrote the below sas code to create the dataset.                                                data new; name ="&name";                                                                                                                                                                                                                  category="&category"; run;

Comment: So i want to check everytime the i run the code whether the same name is available in the dataset. If the same name is available, it will not create the record in the datatset and display message in the html output like "it is already avalable". If the same name is not available in the dataset, it need to create new record and display the message in the HTMl 'new record is created'.